# Odd problem installing Ubuntu on HP Z Book

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, uefi

This is the first time I've tried to install a dual boot Linux partition on a UEFI enabled machine, but I'm not even sure this is a UEFI problem.

The machine is an HP Z Book G5.

I created a Into 18.04.3LTS 64bit install USB stick with UUI and booted into Live Ubuntu no problem from it just to make sure Ubuntu ran OK.

I then choose the 'Install' option within the live running Ubuntu for no other reason than it saved a reboot.

I went through the initial choices including setting up the partitions as I wanted and choosing where to install grub and all looked ok.

I was also given the option of installing 3rd party drivers and had to select a secure boot (?) password to be able to install these.

Everything looked good and so I clicked to start the installation.

After literally a few seconds of the install running I got a message to say that the install had failed because it couldn't copy files off the disc. This was before any reboot or anything.

I rebooted and the USB install stick want recognised as bootable.

I recreated the install USB with UUI but it still wouldn't boot. Oddly at this point that stick wouldn't boot in another, much older (is non UEFI) machine either.

I created a new install USB on a new stick with UUI and the Z book wouldn't boot from that either.

I tried creating the boot stock with Rufus and eventually got a stick that would not ok on the other machine, but on the Z book it tries to bit of the stock but I get a message from the Linux boot loader that 'a serious problem occurred'.

Any ideas?

[image: the error on booting from the install stick now]

Comment: it almost sounds like you tried to install Ubuntu onto the USB install stick

Comment: But I've recreated the install stick from the original ISO and also created a new install stick on another different usb stick.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered a few time over on AskUbuntu - it seems it's an issue with Ubuntu installs and UEFI.

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098183/529174) worked a charm for me, but note that you do have to complete the MOX bit on reboot if you choose to install third party drivers even after the installation completes.